# search/filter in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry my english is not so good but I hope you will understand my problem. 
I made my data base with students names and other details, with all methods, post, get, delete and put. And its all working good. (I am new in programing,begginer, I dont know is it good way to do like I did it).

ime = name // prezime = lastname

```
var studentiDataStore = {
        studenti: [],
        postStudent: function(studijId, ime, prezime, brIndexa){
            this.studenti.push({
                id:this.studenti.length, 
                studijId: studijId,
                ime: ime,
                prezime: prezime,
                brIndexa: brIndexa
             });
            return this.studenti[this.studenti.length-1];
        },
        getStudent: function(id){
            if(id){
                var targetIndex = -1;
                for(var i=0; i<this.studenti.length; i++){
                    if(this.studenti[i].id===id){
                        targetIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(targetIndex>-1){
                    return this.studenti[targetIndex];
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                return this.studenti;
            }
        }
    },
```

Now i have this code to draw my students in HTMl

```
var displayStudents = function(){
        var studenti = studentiDataStore.getStudent();
        var htmlPresentation = [];
        for(var i=0; i<studenti.length; i++){
            htmlPresentation.push('<li class="list-group-item">'+ studenti[i].ime + " " + studenti[i].prezime+'</li>');
        }
        document.getElementById("mainContent").innerHTML = '<ul class="list-group">'+ htmlPresentation.join(" ") + '</ul>'
    };
```

Now i have to make search/filter for my students, i tried to find answer but unsuccessful.
My question is, how to make search filter, when I write first letter(and so on) it show me all names starting with that letter ? Thank you

Comment: you need some kind of backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a text input on top of the list

```
<input type="text" id="searchInput" onkeyup="searchFilter()" placeholder="Search for names..">
```

then add this function in the script

```
function searchFilter() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group")[0];
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {            
        if (li[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp

Comment: it is working now.. i visit a lot that web site but could not solve my problem. now I get it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you maybe could get some help from this working example!

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_table

Answer (score 0):

```
var displayStudents = function(){
        var studenti = studentiDataStore.getStudent();
        var htmlPresentation = [];
        for(var i=0; i<studenti.length; i++){
            if((studenti[i].ime+" "+studenti[i].prezime).startsWith("youname"))
            htmlPresentation.push('<li class="list-group-item">'+ studenti[i].ime + " " + studenti[i].prezime+'</li>');
        }
        document.getElementById("mainContent").innerHTML = '<ul class="list-group">'+ htmlPresentation.join(" ") + '</ul>'
    };
```